# Db2 with SQLAlchemy, how to specify default schema

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, db2

I'm trying to map an existing DB2 database to new python ORM objects.
I wrote a very simple mapper class:

```
class Storage(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'T_RES_STORAGE_SUBSYSTEM'        

    id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True,name='SUBSYSTEM_ID')
    name = Column(String(255),name='NAME')
    namealias = Column(String(256),name='NAME_ALIAS')
```

But when I try to map it, by executing a query it puts the `DB2ADMIN`.tablename in front of every query, which of course lead to errors. If I execute the query manually by prepending `TPC`.tablename to it, then everything works without issues.

How can I specify in a table definition which schema to use?

Comment: What you call "tablespace" is actually a schema. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you I was not sure how to call that :/

Comment: Found the solution after your correction :D Thank you mister

Answer (score 4):

Ok so after the help of mustaccio, I found out that in the `table_args` you have to add `schema`:

```
class Storage(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'T_RES_STORAGE_SUBSYSTEM'
    __table_args__ = {'schema' : 'TPC'}

    id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True,name='SUBSYSTEM_ID')
    name = Column(String(255),name='NAME')
    namealias = Column(String(256),name='NAME_ALIAS')
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Any good ideas for re-using the object across multiple schemas?  (working on a system that has duplicate tables across schemas -> customer1schema.infotable, customer2schema.infotable, ...)

Comment: Found this to change schemas - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595161/sqlalchemy-dynamic-schema-on-entity-at-runtime