# SQLAlchemy multi-schema support

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, database-schema

I am trying to create a database API and I am using Python 2.7 and SQLAlchemy.

The API has to support multiple database platforms including MSSQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite.

The problem with making it multi-platform, is that each database has a slightly different understanding of the word 'schema'. Basically, if I am connected to a MSSQL database I want to include or set the schema, but if I am connecting to a SQLite database I do not.

Another problem is that I am using the declarative_base within SQLAlchemy, and the classes have been created, with the schema specification, before I know what type of database I am connecting to. (The user will connect to the database after the script has started running.) So I don't know what type of schema to assign the table.

Here is a simplified example of my code:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
class Methods(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'methods'
    __table_args__ = {u'schema': 'sname'}

    MethodID = Column('methodid', Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    MethodTypeCV = Column('methodtypecv', nullable=False, index=True)
    MethodCode = Column('methodcode', String(50), nullable=False)
    MethodName = Column('methodname', String(255), nullable=False)
    MethodDescription = Column('methoddescription', String(500))
    MethodLink = Column('methodlink', String(255))
    OrganizationID = Column('organizationid', Integer)
```

I have tried a lot of things, including, setting the schema after the class is created but that doesn't work.I have also tried to use reflection but I can't figure out how to get it to work with the declarative base.

Is there a way to use reflection or a global variable or something to be able to change the schema at runtime, once I have a connection to the database and know what the schema will be?

Comment: Not sure I properly understood your problem. Something like [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#specifying-the-schema-name) does not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a way to change the schema at runtime! I found the answer on the following post:

[sqlalchemy dynamic schema on entity at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595161/sqlalchemy-dynamic-schema-on-entity-at-runtime)